# django websocket connection failed during web socket handshake in js console

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-channels

I am trying django channels in my django projects. i have to fetch data from redis server and populate it in a datatable. I tried and established the code in my custom signin page, and the list of objects was printing there without an error. even connection had no error.

but when i tries to connect it after logged in . it shows this error below in console.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/data/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```